# Qubes fails to install with boot error

Tags: boot, installation

I'm trying to install Qubes 3.1 on a Lenovo G50-30 from a usb drive.

After selecting the option to boot, the system shows a loading bar and the Qubes logo, a few seconds later i get this message:

```
dracut-initqueue[520]: Warning: Could not boot
dracut-initqueue[520]: Warning: /dev/root does not exist
```

I've created the usb drive with rufus and with dd, but both lead to the same result.